# What procedure to use to verify a raw public key (TLS ECDHE_EDCSA ciphersuite)?

Tags: signature, tls

Contrary of verifying a certificate which is a well-known procedure, I am wondering what the procedure is to verify a raw public key 'certificate' (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7250). This certificate, as a matter of fact, does not carry any signature.

Answer (score 3):

It is outside the scope of TLS and must be arranged out of band.

Raw public keys come without any signatures and cannot be verified without additional knowledge. [Section 1 of the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7250#section-1) mentions a few ways how they might be verified in some situations. They all amount to receiving the public key through some other authenticated channel.

> - The TLS client can obtain the TLS server public key from a DNSSEC-
>   secured resource record using DNS-Based Authentication of Named
>   Entities (DANE) [RFC6698].

> - The TLS client or server public key is obtained from a [PKIX]
>   certificate chain from a Lightweight Directory Access Protocol
>   [LDAP] server or web page.

> - The TLS client and server public key is provisioned into the
>   operating system firmware image and updated via software updates.